# Running the same code but with two different datasets (inputs)

Tags: python, function, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I have a code in JupyterLab that consists of several functions spread in several cells. The first function generates a dataset that is used in all other functions after it.

What I have to do is run the same code twice but with one of the functions modified. So it would look like this:

```
data_generating_function() # this function should only be ran once so it generates the same dataset for both trials 
function_1() # this is the function that is to be modified once, so there are two version of this function
function_2() # this function and all functions below it stay the same but should be ran twice
function_3()
function_4()
function_5()
```

So I would run `data_generating_function()` once and generate the dataset. Then I would run one version of `function1()` and all the functions below it, then I would run another version of `function1()` and all the other functions below it.

What would be a good way to implement this? I could obviously duplicate the code and just change some function names, I could also put it all into a single cell and create a for loop. However is there a better way that would ideally preserve multiple cells too?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply iterate over your two choices for the first function:

```
data_generating_function() 
for func1 in (function1a, function1b):
    func1()
    function_2()
    function_3()
    function_4()
    function_5()
```

Answer (score 2):

Apologies if I misunderstood the question, but could you not do the following:

Cell 1:

```
# define all functions
```

Cell 2:

```
dataset = data_generating_function()
```

Cell 3:

```
# Run version 1 of function 1 on dataset
result_1_1 = function_1_v1(dataset)
result_2_1 = function_2(result_1_1)
result_3_1 = function_3(result_2_1)
function_4(result_3_1)
```

Cell 4:

```
# Run version 2 of function 1 on dataset
result_1_2 = function_1_v2(dataset)
result_2_2 = function_2(result_1_2)
result_3_2 = function_3(result_2_2)
function_4(result_3_2)
```

This solution assumes that:

- you define functions with return values
- that passing around the results is not "expensive"

You can also persist the results in a file if the latter is not the case.

To reduce code duplication in function_1, you can add a parameter that switches between the two versions.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to avoid modifying or directly iterating over functions whenever possible. The best thing to do in this case would be to add a boolean parameter to `function1` specifying which version of the function you want to run. It would look something like this:

```py
def function1(isFirstTime):
  if isFirstTime:
    # do stuff the first time
    pass
  else:
    # do stuff the second time
    pass
```

You could then iterate over the functions:

```py
data_generating_function()
for b in (True, False):
  function1(b)
  function2()
  function3()
  # ...
```